# What is short beep/click every 5 seconds from pc speaker of the GA-Z77X-D3H rev 1.1 motherboard mean?

Tags: motherboard

What is short beep/click every 5 seconds from pc speaker of the GA-Z77X-D3H rev 1.1 motherboard mean?

The cpu fan is on as well, but apart from the short click/beeps every 5 seconds there are no other indicators. E.g. no video output, no bios, no nothing.

Comment: Did you read the manual? What did it say?

Comment: @TFM no beep codes in the manual.... Googling on the interent didn't turn up anything either.

Comment: If you're not getting any life signs from the computer, it's the memory. The CPU is fine, as you hear the beeps. Without the memory, nothing else works.